# error code 0x80190194 in wsus windowsupdate.log

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain, wsus, windows-update

My client doenst show itself in the wsus service. how is this possible? I set everything correct following the microsoft guides. now i got the following warnings in my windowsupdate.log file:

EDIT: I deleted the log file because some private data were in it

Comment: Usually this is a IIS problem.
Are you sure that you set the correct ports (8530 is default for an extra site in IIS), the virtual directories in IIS are fine and the client connects at all? (try `wuauclt /detectnow` and `wuauclt /reportnow`). Btw.: you'll find tons of examples by searching for this errorcode.

Comment: wuauclt /detectnow and wuauclt /reportnow in cmd are not working @Lenniey And i set my wsus server on the clients as: http://WSUSCONET not as http://WSUSCONET:8530

Comment: Please elaborate about your configuration. IIS with extra site? Default web-page? default ports? Your client tries to connect to port 80, is that correct in your configuration? How did you assign the client to WSUS? GPO?

Comment: @Lenniey I followed this guide: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc720539%28v=WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Well, you should have used this guide: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn595129.aspx for Server 2012, some things have changed from 2003 to 2012, especially the *port*, try port 8530 in your client configuration

Comment: the port number fixed some warning in the log file, i updated the question with my new log file

Comment: I fixed that error by this:
Net stop wuauserv 
rd /s %windir%\softwaredistribution\ 
Net start wuauserv
Now I only see my server as unassigned computer but not my client. any ideas? @Lenniey

Comment: Again: did you use GPOs to map the client to WSUS? If so, wait for some time or use `gpupdate /force` and try `wuauclt /detectnow` and `/reportnow` from your client.

Comment: @Lenniey i did the gpupdate /force already. but when tpying `wuauclt /detectnow` and `wuauclt /reportnow` nothing is happening, where does the report go to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26420/discussion-between-lenniey-and-user3201911).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26420/discussion-between-lenniey-and-user3201911).
Ports were wrong (80 instead of 8530) and some mistakes in the WSUS GPO.

Works now.